# htaccess замена контента

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как в htaccess задать чтобы он при 404, 403 не перенаправлял на страницу с ошибкой, а подгружал контент страницы с ошибкой?

Если ввести например `https://core.lotus-app.ru/codingru` то он перенаправит на `https://core.lotus-app.ru/404`. Задача сделать так, чтобы клиент оставался на той же странице (`https://core.lotus-app.ru/codingru`), но при этом ему отобразился контент из (`https://core.lotus-app.ru/404`)

Отрывок из .htaccess отвечающий за редирект:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://core.lotus-app.ru/403
ErrorDocument 404 https://core.lotus-app.ru/404
```

**Upd 14.03.2018:** Вопрос более не актуален, перешел на node.js.

Comment: .htaccess покажите свой.

Comment: @Visman показал отрывок

Comment: Пока работаю над вариантом переадресовывать все запросы на один скрипт и оттуда уже показывать нужный контент

Comment: Сейчас так и делается обычно. Единая точка входа в систему и роутер, который вызывает нужный класс с методом по текущему url. Если же url не попадает в список существующих, выдает 404 заголовок и страницу-заглушку. Аналогично и другие ошибки.